# Visual Studio Enterprise; What does the usage scenario mean?

Tags: visual-studio, enterprise, vs-community-edition

In this [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs),  the only edition that does not support **Enterprise** usage is **Community Edition**. I'm curious to know what this usage is for?

So my question is "What is called enterprise scenario"? We are a team of 3 developers, so I really have no clue what this term means at all.

Answer (score 4):

Please read footnote 12 of the link you posted. A team of up to 5 persons can use VS Community for commercial purposes but should not be a part of an Enterprise.

An enterprise, according to Microsoft is: "Enterprise organizations are defined as >250 PCs or > $1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue"

Comment: What does "revenue" mean in this case? What kind of organization would have 250 PCs, but not more than $1 million US Dollars in annual revenue? Even if each employee had three PCs, $1 million in revenue would not allow to pay them minimum wage.